# xenserver - install centos issue

Tags: xenserver

I got a new server with xenserver installed on it and I'm using the xenclient remotely. Can someone let me know what URL I need to use to install from url for centos 5.4 x64? Alternative is to mount the netinstall iso on the server however I can't find any instructions on how to do that.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get a mirror close to your region then you will need to provide the following

```
http://your_mirror  
/5.4/os/x86_64
```

for example http://centos.arcticnetwork.ca/5.5/os/x86_64/  - because some mirrors don't have the 5.4 anymore you may need to search a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set up an ISO library in XenCenter using an existing NFS or CIFS share where you can store the ISO images you want to install from. If you don't have any NFS share yet, I would recommend creating a fileserver VM using the TurnKey Linux [Fileserver appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/fileserver).

This way you don't need to mount the net install ISO, you can simply "insert" it into the VM's optical drive and boot the VM from it. However, if the net install ISO doesn't contain the proper kernel for XenServer, than you should use the "Other" template instead of a "CentOS" template when creating the VM in XenCenter, and convert it into a PV guest after the installation is complete, since you'll get a HVM guest this way. You can find my instructions for that [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/127396/how-to-run-a-turnkey-linux-virtual-machine-on-xenserver/550771#550771).